# Extract most frequent value between two times

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I am new to power Bi and need some help to extract the most frequent value between a time period. Below is the table where you can see the most frequent value between 1 pm and 2 pm time period is E360 and most frequent value between 2 pm and 3 pm is A178. Please help me to do this in Power BI.

```
item    Timestamp                
E360    03/11/2019 01:00:30              
E360    03/11/2019 01:07:02              
E360    03/11/2019 01:08:32              
E360    03/11/2019 01:11:02     
E360    03/11/2019 01:18:03     
E360    03/11/2019 01:20:53     
E360    03/11/2019 01:23:49              
E360    03/11/2019 01:26:31              
E360    03/11/2019 01:50:55              
E360    03/11/2019 01:54:08              
E360    03/11/2019 01:56:21              
E360    03/11/2019 02:04:08              
E360    03/11/2019 02:06:35              
E360    03/11/2019 02:09:13              
E360    03/11/2019 02:11:53              
E360    03/11/2019 02:14:27              
E360    03/11/2019 02:17:08              
A178    03/11/2019 02:19:49              
A178    03/11/2019 02:22:22              
A178    03/11/2019 02:33:49              
A178    03/11/2019 02:36:14              
A178    03/11/2019 02:49:35              
A178    03/11/2019 02:52:56              
A178    03/11/2019 02:55:16              
A178    03/11/2019 02:57:43              
A178    03/11/2019 03:00:31
```

The data which I showed above is raw data and I have created another table in Power BI. I am trying to add a column with the most probable value in that hour. please help me to do this.

```
Timestamp StartTime     Timestamp End Time        Most probable Value
03/11/2019 01:00:00     03/11/2019 02:00:00       E360
03/11/2019 02:00:00     03/11/2019 03:00:00       A178
```

I would like to add a column with most probable value for every hour

Answer (score 1):

In Power BI you can do the following:

Either create a calendar with date-hour resolution and then create a date-hour calculated column in the data table. Or create a calendar with 1 second resolution (not recommended if your data table contains many days)

```
Calendar = 
SELECTCOLUMNS(
    CROSSJOIN(
        CALENDAR(DATE(2019;3;1); DATE(2019;3;31));
        GENERATESERIES(
            0;
            TIME(23;0;0);
            TIME(1;0;0)
        )
    );
    "dateTime";  [Date]& " " &[Value]  
)
```

Calculated column in the Data table:

```
DateHour = 
DATE(
    YEAR(Data[dateTime]); 
    MONTH(Data[dateTime]); 
    DAY(Data[dateTime])
    )& " " & 
    TIME(HOUR(Data[dateTime]); 0; 0)
```

Create a relationship between the calendar and the the new date-hour column.

[image]

Then add the following measure:

```
MostProbableValue = 
MINX (
    TOPN (
        1;
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            VALUES ( Data[item] );
            "Frequency"; CALCULATE ( COUNT ( Data[item] ) )
        );
        [Frequency];
        0
    );
    Data[item]
)
```

Add a second calculated column in the Data table:

```
Timestamp_EndTime = [DateHour]+Time(0; 59; 59)
```

Then you can create a visual table by dragging [DateHour], [Timestamp_EndTime], and the MPV measure. Renaming the [DateHour] column to Timestamp_Start] you end up with a table looking like this:

[image]

N.B: As you write in your table it would be unclear in which bin a value with a timestamp exactly at 02:00:00 would be counted, if not twice. Therefore, the upper limit is + 59min 59 sec. If you still want it looking like the table you write then change the calculated column [Timestamp_EndTime] to +TIME(1;0;0) instead.

Also, if you know you only have a singe value for each timestamp in your data table you don actually need the calendar.

Comment: I have edited the question with the exact results I need. Could you please check and help me out?.  thanks.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you updated but I changed my reply to mimic your table. Though I would recommend you change the limits (as I've done) to avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 0):

```
select item, count(*) cnt
from table
where <date time filter>
group by item
order by 2 desc
```

That will give you counts of each.  and in proper order.  Now to take top row from that set, you can choose variety of techniques based on db engine.  In SQL top 1.  In oracle rownum < 2, etc.  so for example oracle will be

```
select x.*
from
(
    select item, count(*) cnt
    from table
    where <date time filter>
    group by item
    order by 2 desc
) x
where rownum < 2
```